# What is the best way to implement multiple spinners?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I want to know that what will be the best way to implement spinner in a listview. My scenario is I am getting products names, prices and their number from server side. For this I am going to make one main Activity (with one xml) that will contain the listview and a separate adapter class to make the adapter for the listview and that adapter layout. Now I want to ask is this approach will be good as I will be having some operations on spinner selection (getting each spinner (or product) dropdown number, spinner (or product) name and position) and also I will have to handle spinner positions as getview() will render each time? Or you people suggest me some good ideas instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

Having many spinners in a `ListView` is possible but I would imagine in most cases it'd be inconvenient for the user -- too much clutter and moving elements on top of each other. I suggest you create a separate `Fragment` for item details, and only display static items in your `ListView` that will take the user to item details fragment (with spinners and anything else you might need). Take a look at this design pattern: [Multi-pane layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html)